# Can i pass arguments to command in contributes block?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to reusing command with some arguments.
I found key binding can do this with "args" property:

```
{
"key": "cmd+k 8",
"command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
"when": "resourceLangId == 'markdown'",
"args": {
    "name": "Insert bold text"
 }
}
```

so i try to write my package.json/contributes/menus in a similar way and it didnt work:

```
"commands": [
    {
        "command": "extension.sayHello",
        "title": "Say Hello"
    }
],
"menus": {
    "editor/context": [
        {
            //menu one
            "command": "extension.sayHello",
            "group": "navigation@1",
            "args": {
                "text": "Say Hello 1!"
            }
        },
        {
            //menu two
            "command": "extension.sayHello",
            "group": "navigation@2",
            "args": {
                "text": "Say Hello 2!"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to pass "text" to command handler function.
Are there any feature to archive similar result?

Comment: I would also love to know this. Coming from Sublime Text development I am used to it! Did you ever find an answer or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, founded it on Github firstly, but i wanted to share some info that i actually founded within many resources and code-analysis:

So, even now, in a date when i writing it down here, there is still no normal way for making it in `package.json`... Like, at all...

But, by looking at some other extensions, i see that some of them are actually founded another way for making it working:

To do this, we need to look at the `vscode.commands.registerCommand` command.

```js
function commands.registerCommand(command: string, callback: (...args: any[]) => any, thisArg?: any): vscode.Disposable
```

That means, we can use third parameter to actually send some data.
As an example:
`package.json`:

```json
"contributes": {
...
    "menus": {
        "view/title": [
            {
              "command": "extension.addEntryOne",
              "when": "view == extension",
              "group": "navigation"
            },
            {
              "command": "extension.addEntryTwo",
              "when": "view == extension2",
              "group": "navigation"
            }
        ]
    },
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "extension.addEntryOne",
            "title": "Add entry One",
            "icon":"$(diff-insert)"
        },
        {
            "command": "remospace.addEntryTwo",
            "title": "Add entry Two",
            "icon":"$(diff-insert)"
        }
    ]
...
}
```

`extension.ts`:

```js
//
//Activation part before
//
let Execution = function(this: any){
    console.log(this)
}
let entryOne = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.addEntryOne', Execution,{from:'one'});
let entryTwo = vscode.commands.registerCommand('remospace.addEntryTwo', Execution,{from:'one'});

context.subscriptions.push(entryOne,entryTwo);
```

In this case, we can bypass issue when we need to do same thing with different args. Yes, this may not be the best solution to do it, but at least this is one of it.